# How to Use String instead of ObjectId in "wither" Rust?

Tags: mongodb, rust, rust-cargo, serde

I have this code here:

```rust
pub struct Account {
    #[serde(rename = "_id", skip_serializing_if = "Option::is_none")]
    pub id: Option<ObjectId>,
    pub email: String,
}
```

And I want to change "ObjectId" to String so I can use [Ulid](https://docs.rs/ulid/latest/ulid/).

Comment: `ObjectId` is defined here: https://docs.rs/bson/1.2.0/bson/oid/struct.ObjectId.html and has the method `to_hex` which produces a `String`. Did you try to use that? I guess you can't change the type of `id` as stated here: https://docs.rs/wither/latest/wither/prelude/trait.Model.html `Ensure that you have a field named id, of type Option<ObjectId>, with at least the following serde attributes: #[serde(rename="_id", skip_serializing_if="Option::is_none")]`

Comment: It doesn't seem like that's supported, and [this old issues](https://github.com/thedodd/wither/issues/47) seems to indicate it's going against the plans entirely ([see also](https://github.com/thedodd/wither/issues/92)).

Comment: Apparently there's an other driver called [avocado](https://h2co3.github.io/avocado/) (possibly a hostile [kinda-fork](https://github.com/thedodd/wither/issues/47#issuecomment-569451876) of wither), but they specifically advertise support for non-`ObjectId` keys. On the other hand, it seems dead. YMMV.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this solution, described here: https://docs.rs/bson/latest/bson/oid/struct.ObjectId.html

```
pub struct Account {
    #[serde(serialize_with = "bson::serde_helpers::serialize_object_id_as_hex_string")
    pub id: Option<ObjectId>,
    pub email: String,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need String use

```
let str_id: String = account.id.unwrap().to_hex();
```

Answer (score 0):

check this it worked for me using MongoDB crate but you can give it a try [Solution](https://docs.rs/bson/latest/bson/oid/struct.ObjectId.html#:%7E:text=%23%5Bserde(serialize_with%20%3D%20%22bson%3A%3Aserde_helpers%3A%3Aserialize_object_id_as_hex_string%22)%5D)